# How to escape string in Ruby to protect against SQL Injection? (No Rails)

Tags: ruby, sql-injection

I just wanted to know how can we escape an SQL query (string) in Ruby to prevent SQL Injection. please note I am not using Rails framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If possible, use the Ruby DBI module, and instead of trying to quote your strings, use parametrized prepared queries, like this:

```
dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:test:localhost", "testuser", "testpass")
sth = dbh.prepare("INSERT INTO people (id, name, height) VALUES(?, ?, ?)")
File.open("people.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    name, height = line.chomp.split("\t")
    sth.execute(nil, name, height)
  end
end
```

Quoting will be handled properly for you, and injections will be a thing of the past.

Edit: Note that this example shows nil being passed as the first parameter to execute(). It corresponds to the first ? in the query, and is translated to "NULL" by the DBI module. The other parameters are similarly properly quoted and inserted into the query.

Comment: Why even insert an id field? With normal design this would be automatically incremented.

Comment: It's only an example. But note that the first parameter to execute() is simply nil, and the corresponding parameter in the query (the first question mark) is for id. "id" is being inserted as NULL in this example.

Comment: I wanted to know the same thing like the OP, but I wanted to just write SQL statements to a file, so I guess prepared statements are off the table then? Could I (ab)use .inspect for escaping strings?

Answer (score 4):

Write a wee function to quote strings. I think Rails just uses something like this:

```
def quote_string(v)
  v.to_s.gsub(/\\/, '\&\&').gsub(/'/, "''")
end
```

Comment: See greyfade's answer.  Or Andy Lester's.  This is just a bad idea.

Comment: Sometimes you're working on a one-off migration script and have no extra gems installed (no rails or dbi) and when that happens this is an effective solution. In pretty much any other situation you should use prepared statements of course.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use rails, you could just `require 'activerecord'` and use it as you would in rails (define models and use those). What you're doing there is just re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to sanitize your data.  Use prepared statements.  See also http://bobby-tables.com/ruby.html